How to construct a type from a union of object types with a given list of keys
I have three types
type TypeA = {
  name: "A",
  prop1: string,
}

type TypeB = {
  name: "B",
  prop2: string,
}

type Default = {
  name: string,
}

type AllTypes = TypeA | TypeB | Default

Now, I have a union of approved keys to use to construct an object type.
type Approved = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D"

I want to have a type like following:
type Result = {
  A?: TypeA,
  B?: TypeB,
  C?: Default,
  D?: Default,
}

Is that possible? I tried something like this but it's not working as expected
type FromUnion<T extends AllTypes, K extends Approved> = {
    [K in Approved]?: Extract<T, {name: K}>
}

FromUnion<AllTypes, "A">  // gives me the `AllTypes` type.


• "It's not working as expected" Can you [edit] to show that? Are you meant to write FromUnion<TypeA | TypeB | Default, Approved> or something? • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz, yes that works! Please submit.

"gives me the AllTypes type." Hmm, no it doesn't, it gives you {A?: TypeA, B?: TypeB, C?: never, D?: never}.

One approach is as follows:
type Result = { [K in Approved]?:
    OrDefault<Extract<AllTypes, { name: K }>, Default>
}

type OrDefault<T, D> = [T] extends [never] ? D : T;

It's a mapped type where the key K iterates over the members of Approved. It's similar to what you're doing, where we Extract the member of AllTypes whose name property is of type K.  This gives you TypeA for A and TypeB for B.  But for C and D this gives never because there is no such member of AllTypes.
That's where OrDefault<T, D> comes in.  That's a utility type which checks if T is never. If so, it returns D. Otherwise it returns T.  It does this via a conditional type (where we wrap the check in [⋯] to avoid distributing over T, see Why do we use square brackets `[]` in conditionals?)
And instead of Extract<AllTypes, { name: K }>, we write OrDefault<Extract<AllTypes, { name: K }>, Default>, which gives us
/* type Result = {
    A?: TypeA;
    B?: TypeB;
    C?: Default;
    D?: Default;
} */

as desired.
Playground link to code
